# how to create a list and test for a hangman game

Tags: python, python-3.x

So right now I'm creating a hangman game. I'm a beginner programmer and I'm kind of stuck right now.

I need to create a list for the program to pick a word from and then use that word for the hangman game. In addition I have to create a test to check if the player lost. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
def hangman(secretWord):
        lettersGuessed = []
        availableLetters = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
        mistakes = 8
        while mistakes > 0:
            if wordFound(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
                print("You figured it out!")
                break
            print(displayWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
            print("Available letters:", " ".join(availableLetters))
            print("You have", mistakes, "mistakes left")
            guess = input("guess letter: ")
            if guess.lower() in availableLetters:
                availableLetters.remove(guess)
                lettersGuessed.append(guess)
                if guess in secretWord:
                    print("Good Guess!")
                else:
                    mistakes -= 1
                    print("Bad guess.")
            else:
                print("You already guessed that one")
        #Create a test to see if player lost.
        #print a message if the player lost.

    def displayWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
        word = []
        for i in secretWord:
            if i in lettersGuessed:
                word.append(i)
            else:
                word.append("_")
        return(" ".join(word))

    def wordFound(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
        for i in secretWord:
            if i not in lettersGuessed:
                return False
        return True
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what about it doesn't work?

Comment: This code seems reasonable to me. What test do you need? If there's no more tries left the player has lost, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you try to create a list like:

```
list1 = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4']
```

And then select random word:

```
random.randint(1, 10)
```

Or read a txt with the words and then slecet a random word:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random

with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as f:
    list1 = [i.rstrip() for i in f.readlines()]

word = random.choice(list1)
```

default.txt:

```
worda
wordb
wordc
wordd
```

For the test, you can simply use mistakes variable:

```
if mistakes == 0:
    print("You lost, the word was {0}".format(secretWord))
```

Comment: It would be simpler to use `random.choice(list1)`.

Comment: True, i gonna change it, Thanks!